# Office 365 outlook appointment addin commands for ribbon does not show up

Tags: ms-office, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

We are trying to publish our app to the office store but can not pass the following condition.

Your add-in must use add-in commands since it triggers on all messages or all appointments. Add-in commands have been introduced as they lead to a better, much more discoverable, native and engaging experience To find out how to implement add-in commands, please see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267547.aspx

We have a really simple manifest that is provided below. The addin works nice in the webbrowsers but in outlook on windows/desktop the command does not load. We have tried to trace the http-traffic but cant see any calls to our website so my guess is that we have som kind of error in our manifest? Any suggestions in how to debug this and see any errors?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->

<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>guid</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CompanyName</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>

  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Display Name Test"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="[URL]App%2064x64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="[URL]App%20128x128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="[URL]" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                  <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>commandFunction</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="[URL]App16x16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="[URL]App32x32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="[URL]App80x80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="[URL]"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel"  DefaultValue="Test"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties. This is an example of a button that opens a task pane."/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Test2"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Test3"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Supertip Title, use a resource string from ShortStrings instead of LongStrings. I tried that on my Outlook client and it works for me.

So I changed this line:

```
<Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
```

to:

```
<Title resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
```

And then I went to my Calendar, clicked on "New Appointment", and your add-in shows up in my ribbon.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Add-in commands currently only work in Outlook 2016 and 2013 (with the March 8, 2016 Security Update).  If you are testing with those versions, note that if the user selects an item in the calendar but doesn't open the pop-out, the add-in's ribbon group won't be visible in the ribbon.

See: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook